# Are there any alternatives to using system ping utility or sending ICMP packets for creating a network condition monitor?

Tags: python, ping, network-monitoring

I've been writing and maintaining a personal use utility that pings `8.8.8.8` every 1s and displays a pip indicating the network's condition for a while now, and due to the fact that my network appears to have inherent ~1.7% packet drop, I made it run two PING.EXE processes in parallel, with a timeout of 950ms so as to differentiate between randomly dropped packets and brief outages(these also happen)

Now, the problem is: I don't have enough control over the pings, and I've run into issues with the fact that PING.EXE's delay of 1s is not exact enough, and as the processes drift, I randomly get [heavily degenerate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s0VK.png) cases like 60 pips correlating to **107.24s** instead of the intended 60s.

I could probably work around this issue by launching a new ping process every second, but that's an extremely inelegant solution, and with non-negligible overhead(on Windows at least) besides, and I'd like to refrain from needing to manually send ICMP packets because then I'd need to run my utility with administrative privileges.

Apologies for the open-ended "is there anything" question, but without knowing anything, I don't know what to ask for.

---

EDIT: I've tried lowering the timeout from 999ms to 900ms and even 750ms, but PING.EXE either does not adhere to it, or it does so improperly, because this keeps happening, although the issue is *much* smaller - +15s under maximum network load. Probably acceptable enough, but...

Comment: Vaguely thinking maybe [fping](https://fping.org/) though it's for a different use case than yours really I guess.

Comment: You could use the [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module to create an object representing each ping with the desired timeout. Then have a callback to check at the end if you have received the ping, a timeout, or an error.

Comment: The use of threading in this fashion would still require spawning a new PING.EXE process every second, which I'd prefer to avoid. The solution I'm thinking of now is duplicating the last pip whenever the accumulated drift is >1s.

Comment: *> would still require spawning a new PING.EXE process every second...* True, but not if you do the ICMP packets natively in Python. Have a look at [MultiPing](https://github.com/romana/multi-ping/) which does not rely on a shell call.

Comment: @dawg Like I said in the original post, I would like to avoid my script requiring administrative privileges, which are necessary for sending ICMP packets.

Comment: It is an insoluble problem as stated then. `ping` itself has `root` group membership (at least on *nix) and your either need to use `ping` or write or use a similar utility with `root` group membership or privileges. There is no shortcut to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to replicate `ping` exactly in Python, you would need administrator privileges to send ICMP packets to a host.

You *could* instead rely on TCP packets and tap the http port. That does not  require admin privileges. Neither is it *quite* as accurate but it is an more accurate portrayal of web browsing ability.

Simplifying [this](https://github.com/yantisj/tcpping) TCP ping code:

```
import sys
import socket
import time
import signal
from timeit import default_timer as timer

host = "google.com"
port = 80

# Default to 10000 connections max
maxCount = 10000
count = 0

# Pass/Fail counters
passed = 0
failed = 0

def getResults():
    """ Summarize Results """

    lRate = 0
    if failed != 0:
        lRate = failed / (count) * 100
        lRate = "%.2f" % lRate

    print("\nTCP Ping Results: Connections (Total/Pass/Fail): [{:}/{:}/{:}] (Failed: {:}%)".format((count), passed, failed, str(lRate)))

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    """ Catch Ctrl-C and Exit """
    getResults()
    sys.exit(0)

# Register SIGINT Handler
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

# Loop while less than max count or until Ctrl-C caught
while count < maxCount:

    # Increment Counter
    count += 1

    success = False

    # New Socket
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # 1sec Timeout
    s.settimeout(1)

    # Start a timer
    s_start = timer()

    # Try to Connect
    try:
        s.connect((host, int(port)))
        s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RD)
        success = True

    # Connection Timed Out
    except socket.timeout:
        print("Connection timed out!")
        failed += 1
    except OSError as e:
        print("OS Error:", e)
        failed += 1

    # Stop Timer
    s_stop = timer()
    s_runtime = "%.2f" % (1000 * (s_stop - s_start))

    if success:
        print("Connected to %s[%s]: tcp_seq=%s time=%s ms" % (host, port, (count-1), s_runtime))
        passed += 1

    # Sleep for 1sec
    if count < maxCount:
        time.sleep(1)

# Output Results if maxCount reached
getResults()
```

Once you can create a 'ping' you could encapsulate the result of each time / ping result into an object stream to display as you wish.

Comment: So this basically just initiates a TCP connection to google and measures the amount of time the handshake takes to complete?

I've tested this briefly, the results seem to be around 10+-10ms higher than PING.EXE output, which is a bit too much variation for me.

Nonetheless, it is what I asked for, we'll see if any other answers happen(I'll try googling some more myself), if not I'll accept your answer, and thanks either way.

As for my utility, I ended up settling on duplicating pips when the time drift accumulates to >1s.

Comment: Also, hmm, would an UDP version, or another protocol, be potentially more accurate?

Answer (score 0):

[aping](https://www.iea-software.com/aping) supports this.

The following example sends 3 ping requests 50ms apart to 8.8.8.8 each second with a 800ms timeout.

```
aping -n 3 -i 50 -w 800 -sleep 1 8.8.8.8
```

Timing of each scan (-sleep 1) is adjusted by execution time of prior scans to ensure a constant one second cadence regardless of response time / instances where all three packets are not responded to.

Admin is not required on Windows.